# remove duplicate reference in Matlab

Tags: matlab, reference, duplicates

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the duplicate abs(x-z) and still keeping it in one line:
f(x(find(abs(x-z)==min(abs(x-z)))))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [lightspeed toolbox](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/), which is anyway highly recommanded, and use its argmin function, and do:

```
f(x(argmin(abs(x-z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
d = abs(x-z); f(x(d==min(d(:)))); clear d;
```

But it's hardly any more readble than your original code.